# If every closed form over $U$ is exact, the same is true to $f(U)$..

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

> Let $f: U \to \Bbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable function with differentiable inverse $f^{-1}: f(U) \to \Bbb{R}^n$. If every closed form over $U$ is exact, the same is true to $f(U)$.

I'm having trouble solving this problem. I know that if $\omega$ any $k$-form over $f(U)$, then we can find $\eta$ such that $f^{\ast}\omega = d\eta$, since $f^{\ast}$ maps $k$-forms over $f(U)$ into $k$-forms over $U$. Also,
$$\omega = (f^{-1}\circ f)^{\ast}\omega = (f^{-1})^{\ast}f^{\ast}\omega = d(f^{-1})^{\ast}\eta = d\beta,$$
hence $\omega$ is exact. Is this correct?

Comment: Would it be "If $\omega$ is a closed form on $f(U)$, then there exists $\eta$ such that $\omega=d\eta$"? Why did you put $f^*$ into it?

Comment: @Learning because $f^{\ast}$ maps $\omega$ into a $k$-form over $U$, and over $U$, every closed form is exact.

Comment: ah ok then you must have made a typo with "$\omega$ closed over $f(U)$". it should be "$\omega$ any $k$-form in $f(U)$".

Comment: Also how do you prove the implicit equality $(f^{-1})^*d\eta=d((f^{-1})^*\eta)$?

Comment: @Learning I don't prove it for this problem because Spivak's book proved in the chapter. Anyway, Spivak uses induction over $\omega$ and simple properties of differential forms.

Comment: The rest looks fine to me

Comment: I hope differentiable means "sufficiently differentiable" or smooth. You also have the functions in the wrong order. You need to do $(f\circ f^{-1})^*\omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of errors here. You must start with a *closed* form in order for it to have any hope of being exact. So start with a closed form $\omega$ on $f(U)$. Then $\phi = f^*\omega$ is closed, since $d\phi = df^*\omega = f^*(d\omega) = 0$. Therefore $\phi$ is exact and can be written as $\phi = d\psi$. We then claim that
$$\omega = d((f^{-1})^*\psi),$$
as 
$$d((f^{-1})^*\psi) = (f^{-1})^*(d\psi) = (f^{-1})^*\phi =(f^{-1})^*(f^*\omega) = (f\circ f^{-1})^*\omega = \omega.$$